# I am confused how I am meant to control access in a API Gateway Rest API using Amazon Cognito User Pools

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have spent 2 days trying to understand the idea behind Amazon Cognito Access Control for a site I am trying to create. Its very simple:

- The site allows users to create posts
- Anyone (anonymous users and signed in users) should be able to see posts
- Only signed in users should be able to create posts
- Only the original author should be able to edit his own posts

Now heres the things I think I have understood about amazon cognito:

- Cognito user pools are meant for rest interfaces and identity pools are used to create temporary amazon roles with specific policies so people logged on to my service can access aws services such as dynamodb or s3 buckets directly
- In order to make an authorized request to my rest interface, a user has to sign in using the cognito UI and receive an access token, that has to be sent with every request to the Rest API to verify the request
- The verification can be done automatically using the cognito authorizer right in API Gateway or by redirecting the access token to lambda and verifying it directly there
- If its done with the cognito authorizer, the username and other information cannot be read from within lambda
- If I use AWS Amplify to handle request authorization on the client side, the access tokens are renewed automatically

But theres still some questions I have about the whole process:

- Are Cognito usernames guaranteed to be unique? And if there not, how can I let the user choose a guaranteed unique username after registration or using a google login?
- Are access tokens equivalent to session cookies?
- If I am meant to handle access tokens on inside a lambda script, is there a library or service I can use? Because I haven't found a way to verify the token or get the user associated with the token
- Why doesn't the built in authorizer redirect the user information to the lambda script?
- Is there a prebuilt lambda authorizer that I could plug into API Gateway directly, that would allow both signed in and anonymous users to make requests to it and redirects user information to the lambda script? Because I couldn't find one in the repository or anywhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I dont have all the answers, but I have some that will hopefully direct you:

> Are Cognito usernames guaranteed to be unique

A User cannot signup if a username/email is already used. You need to specify which field to use for username (ie email or username)

> Are access tokens equivalent to session cookies?

No, an access token is normally communicated within the `authorization` header of a request via a bearer token strategy and the cookie is within the `cookie` header. Some services will validate a cookie, others (especially machine to machine) will validate an `authorization` header. In some cases, developers may decide to make these the same, but its not always this way.

> If I am meant to handle access tokens on inside a lambda script, is there a library or service I can use.

If you are looking to get context (like the username, which is encoded within the JWT string) of an access token, then you can use JWT decode functions. By the time the request hits lambda, the Authorizor has already validated it, so you do not need to do the same again.

> Why doesn't the built in authorizer redirect the user information to the lambda script

Because not all services need/want it. Its better for consuming services to do what they need with the context after they decode the token

> Is there a prebuilt lambda authorizer that I could plug into API Gateway directly, that would allow both signed in and anonymous users to make requests to it and redirects user information to the lambda script?

This question shows a problem with your understanding of rest. An API should leverage CRUD actions; so `Create` may only be granted to contributors, `Read` may be granted publicly, `Update` may only be granted to owners, `Delete` may only be granted to owners. The above is a generalization, but you need an API strategy; when you develop this strategy, you will realize there is no "easy" button.

In general, I would have 2 API Gateways, one for read-only purposes and another for managing content. This keeps it simple and allows you to scale in different ways (ie you may want your contributors to not be blocked by read-only uses in situations of scale issues).

Also, adopting a path based strategy can help with simplifying who has access to what resources. Take the below example:

a user sends a POST request to `/api/blog/` to create a new blog (resulting in `/api/blog/:blogId`). The `/api/blog/` endpoint is not "owned" by any specific contributor. Later the user makes an update to `/api/blog/1234-abcd`...now your service must make an additional call to see if that resource is owned by the user (this is called the "entitlement" process). In psuedo-sql, you would `SELECT created_by FROM blogs WHERE id='1234-abcd'` and then see if the `created_by` field matches your user id.

Anywho, you get the point :) This becomes even MORE complex if you allow teams/multiple users the ability to modify resources...and new we get into RBAC (role based access control), which is a much longer topic.

Sorry for the digression, but hopefully this gives you more direction.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it clears a lot of things up. One thing I have figured out in the mean time is that cognito tokens are JWT token, which encodes all the user information with it so I would add that to your answer for other people.    
So you would create 2 different API Gateway rest APIs, with duplicate resources and duplicate GET methods for both public and authorized access? Basically have the client hit either one depending on whether the user is logged in or not? Then I could just use the same lambda for both and just see whether or not the authorization handler is present

Comment: I did add JWT context in that novel :) `If you are looking to get context of an access token, then you can use JWT decode functions`. I would have one API gateway with a cognito authorizer and the other without. The resources wouldnt be duplicate, for example, the public interface doesnt need an endpoint to `create` resources. I always think of people managing content as paid users, so they may have two different gateways. I would look to create lambdas **per** microservice, otherwise they can become monolithic very quickly

Comment: Yes it wouldn't have duplicate methods (unless I want to personalize GET methods for signed in users) but I still pretty sure it would have the same models and resources (as in endpoint names) twice, but I guess thats not a big deal. Anyway thanks for the pointers, I think I now understand how I can implement my service